# Internal server error while uploading files using files_upload in dropbox python api

Tags: python, dropbox, python-3.4, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a local csv file to dropbox account using files_upload method in python dropbox api.It is raising an internal server error. Previously,it was working fine.Below is my code.

```
import dropbox
from dropbox.files import WriteMode
from dropbox.exceptions import ApiError, AuthError
d = dropbox.Dropbox('xxxxxxxxx')
with open(pricing_plan_unit_no_data_csv_path, 'rb') as f:
# We use WriteMode=overwrite to make sure that the settings in the file
# are changed on upload
BACKUPPATH = '/IH_Permit_and_Title_processing/Title_input_for_KNIME/' +  lastmonth.strftime("%m_%Y") + '/' +  'plan_unit_'+lastmonth.strftime("%m_%Y")+'_nodata.csv'
print("Uploading " + pricing_plan_unit_no_data_csv_path + " to Dropbox as " + BACKUPPATH + "...")
try:
  d.files_upload(f.read(), BACKUPPATH, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
  f.close()
except ApiError as err:
# This checks for the specific error where a user doesn't have
# enough Dropbox space quota to upload this file
   if (err.error.is_path() and   err.error.get_path().error.is_insufficient_space()):
    sys.exit("ERROR: Cannot back up; insufficient space.")
   elif err.user_message_text:
       print(err.user_message_text)
       sys.exit()
   else:
      print(err)
      sys.exit()
```

Below is the error

```
File "C:/Users/Kcs-Lpt-00020/PycharmProjects/IH_Permit_and_Tiltle_Processing/pricinginformationdropbox.py", line 301, in 
d.files_upload(f.read(), BACKUPPATH, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py", line 1252, in   files_upload
 f,
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 249, in request
  timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 341, in request_json_string_with_retry
  timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox.py", line 430, in request_json_string
 raise InternalServerError(request_id, r.status_code, r.text)
 dropbox.exceptions.InternalServerError:     InternalServerError('a12a84f64e3ae72a9b09c1d6831648f0', 500, '')
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/98 ]

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working fine.